# iPhone Store ID won't validate in a Facebook App

Tags: ios, facebook, app-store, facebook-apps

I'm trying to set the iPhone Store ID on our Facebook App to start a Mobile Add Campaign, and every time I try to save the profile it shows an error stating the following:

> We were unable to retrieve your iPhone Store ID from the iTunes App Store. Please double-check your ID and try again later.

Our app is already live and accessible in the New Zealand app store only. Is it required to have it available in the US store for Facebook to be able to validate it?

Comment: It doesn't matter if they don't find your id, at least when I tried, you could even leave it blank

Comment: You need it for advertising puproses. Any idea why that happened and any resolution please?